# Why is Ubuntu 18.04 halting after login since upgrade from 17.10?

Tags: graphics, login, 18.04

I have an Acer Aspire VX 15 (Intel Core i7, NVidia Geforce GTX 1050, 32 Gb RAM, HDD 1Tb).

I had Ubuntu 17.10 installed and everything was working fine. Then I upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04 and now, after I login via GDM (in graphics mode) the system halts. It becomes completely frozen.

However, if I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, switch to text mode, and then login in the console, the system works fine (in text mode) and do not halt.

Does anybody else has a similar problem?

Do you know how to fix this or how I can diagnose the problem?

Comment: What exactly do you see on the screen when the system "freezes" after log-in into the graphical session?

Comment: The Gnome desktop loads and for a few seconds I am able to use the system. Then, the screen freezes with whatever it is displaying (file manager, gedit, or just the desktop if I have not started any application).

Answer (score 1):

I seems the problem was with the graphics driver. The default installation uses the Nouveau driver. After I installed the NVIDIA recommended driver (nvidia-driver-390) everything seems to be working fine.